# Simple if else command latex to bolden italic/nonitalic words

Tags: macros, ifthenelse

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bld}[1]{%
  \ifx\f@shape=it
    \textbf{#1}
  \else
    \emph{\textbf{#1}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\emph{This is a \bld{definition}.}\\
This is a \bld{definition}.
\end{document}
```

Somehow it does not quite what I want it to do: `\bld{word}` should produce a bold and italic word if the word is not already italic and just a bold word if the word is already italic. Another question is, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: `\newcommand{\bld}[1]{\emph{\textbf{#1}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that `\emph` already does it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand{\bld}[1]{\emph{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\emph{This is a \bld{definition}.}

This is a \bld{definition}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that the word is italic notwithstanding the environment, just do

```
\newcommand{\bld}[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand{\bld}[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\emph{This is a \bld{definition}.}

This is a \bld{definition}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I was not too clear: I would like that the word definition is also italic, which is not the case. Thus I wanted to do an if/else to check whether the current style is italic or not. Sorry.

Comment: No, it wasn't clear.`;-)` I added the trick.